# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {state, addBlog}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-context

I created page as Context creator but when i run app on android i have this error ( Error: Objects are not valid as a React child ( Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {state, addBlog}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.)
and i have no idea whats wrong

Here is my code:

```
export default (reducer,actions,initialstate)=>{
    const Context=createContext();
    const Provider=({children})=>{
        const [state,dispatch]=useReducer(reducer,initialstate);
        const boundActions={};
        for(let key in actions){
            boundActions[key]=actions[key](dispatch);
        };
        return (
        <Context.Provider value={{state,...boundActions}}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
        );
    }
    return {Context,Provider};
}
```